# Вывод всех вариантов доп поля WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Задался вопросом, как вывести на фронтэнде WordPress все возможные значения одного произвольного поля (в данном случае, задается тег select, в админке я варианты вижу, а на клиентскую часть никак что-то не получается их вывести). Поля созданы при помощи Advanced Custom Fields.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию `get_field_object()`

```
$field = get_field_object($field_name);
```

Она вернет полное описание поля в массиве примерно такого вида:

```
array(
    'ID'                => 0,
    'key'               => '',
    'label'             => '',
    'name'              => '',
    'prefix'            => '',
    'type'              => 'text',
    'value'             => null,
    'menu_order'        => 0,
    'instructions'      => '',
    'required'          => 0,
    'id'                => '',
    'class'             => '',
    'conditional_logic' => 0,
    'parent'            => 0,
    'wrapper'           => array(
        'width'             => '',
        'class'             => '',
        'id'                => ''
    )
);
```